# How to pass args in line by line in Java?

Tags: java, string, input, line, args

`Public static void main(String[] args)` only accepts inputs as one line, right? I want to pass arguments as line by line. Please help me.
I am damn sure there is some way. My condition is "Program should accept input on console in line by line".Please help me.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: how do you manage to execute the command with line breaks? Hitting return will terminate the input on all consoles that I'm aware of...

Comment: `String[]` args accepts arguments passed with the invocation of the `java` command; that's always one line.  Input not passed already at startup time is just read from stdin; use `BufferedReader` and friends.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to pass in several lines of arguments, write your information in a txt file and then parse that file using a BufferedReader in your program.

Comment: I am damn sure there is some way. My condition is "Program should accept input on console in line by line".Please help me.

Comment: The best way to adhere to that condition would be to have the program read the console during runtime from stdin, like [this](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-input-from-console-java/).

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to control the arguments passed to your application from inside your application.

Answer (score 0):

You can input the data from console like this:

```
BufferedReader buffReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));       
...
String input = buffReader.readLine();
```